# udp send from driver

Tags: linux, udp, driver, scheduler, dma

I have a driver that needs to:

1. receive data from an FPGA
2. DMA data to another another device (DSP) for encoding
3. send the encoded data via UDP to an external host

The original plan was to have the application handle step 3, but the application doesn't get the processor in time to process the data before the next set of data arrives from the FPGA.

Is there a way to force the scheduler (from the driver) to run my application?

If not, I think work queues are likely the solution I need to use, but I'm not sure how/where to call into the network stack/driver to accomplish the UDP transfers from the work queues.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to discover why the application "can't get the data fast enough".

Your memory bandwith is probably vastly superior to the thypical ethernet bandwith, so even if passing data from the driver to the application involves copying.

If the udp link is not fast enough in userspace, it won't be faster in kernelspace.
What you need to do is :

- understand why your application is not fast enough, maybe by stracing it.
- implement queuing in userspace.

You can probably split your application in two thread, sharing buffer list

- thread A waits for the driver to have data available, and puts it at the tail of the list.
- thread B reads  data from the head of the list, and sends it through UDP. If for some reason thread B is busy waiting for a particular buffer to be sent, the fifo fills a bit, but as long as the UDP link bandwith is larger than the rate of data coming from the DSP you should be fine.

Moving things into the kernel does not makes things magically faster, it is just MUCH harder to code and debug and trace.